# Nativescript Angular Multiple Screen Support

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

how do I accomplish multi screen support for my application built with Nativescript + Angular? Thanks!

Comment: If you like to change the style of elements based on device size, simply bind the class based on the [device resolution](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/platform#basics) / type. Or you could completely render / load a different component using ngIf based on similar conditions.

Comment: Alright will try doing that. Thanks